# Getting list of running docker containers using docker-py

Tags: docker, dockerpy

I'm using [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) to manage docker containers for one of my apps. I want to retrieve the list of all running containers, identical to `docker ps`. But the `containers` method only returns an empty list.

```
>>> import docker
>>> c = docker.Client()
>>> container = c.create_container(image='base', command='/bin/bash', stdin_open=True, tty=True, name='docker-test')
>>> container
{u'Id': u'1998f08a031d8632400264af667d93162465a04348b61144a4c730c7c4462875', u'Warnings': None}
>>> c.start(container)
>>> c.containers(quiet=False, all=True, trunc=True, latest=False, since=None, before=None, limit=-1)
[]
```

But, of course, doing `$ docker ps` gives me this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
1998f08a031d        base:latest             /bin/bash           3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            docker-test
```

What am I missing out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I figured out what was wrong. The client and servers didn't have the same versions. When I re-initialize `docker.Client` with the correct version number, it returns a list of all the containers running.